# Parse JSON field with jq and output repeatedly for every child

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
    {
        "field1":"foo",
        "array":[
            {
                child_field1:"c1_1",
                child_field2:"c1_2"
            },
            {
                child_field1:"c2_1",
                child_field2:"c2_2"
            }
         ]...
    }
```

and using `jq`, I would like to return the following output, where the value of `field1` is repeated for every child element.:

```
    foo,c1_1,c1_2
    foo,c2_1,c2_2
    ...
```

I can access each field separately, am having trouble returning the desired result above.

Can this be done with jq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jq -r '.array[] as $a | [.field1, $a.child_field1, $a.child_field2] | @csv'
```

Does the right thing for the sample data you provided, but I freely admit there are lots of ways to do that kind of thing in `jq`, and that was only the first one which sprang to mind.

I fed it through `@csv` because it seemed like that was what you wanted, but if you prefer the actual output, exactly as you have written, then:

```
jq -r '.array[] as $a | "\(.field1),\($a.child_field1),\($a.child_field2)"'
```

will produce it

Answer (score 0):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '.field1 as $f1 | .array[] 
       | [$f1, .[]] 
       | join(",")' input.json
```

The output:

```
foo,c1_1,c1_2
foo,c2_1,c2_2
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, there's no need for `reduce` or `to_entries', or to list the fields explicitly -- one can simply exploit jq's backtracking behavior:

```
.field1 as $f
| .array[]
| [$f, .[]]
| @csv
```

As pointed out by @MatthewLDaniel, there are many alternatives to using @csv here.